# Como usar sobrecarga de construtor em TypeScript?

Tags: construtor, typescript, sobrecarga

Em linguagens com o C#, por exemplo, é possível utilizar a sobrecarga do construtor da forma apresentada abaixo:

```
    public class Teste{
        public Teste(bool a, int b, string c){ }
        public Teste(bool a, int b){ }
        public Teste(bool a){ }
    }
```

Depois de algum tempo procurando eu consegui realizar a sobrecarga de construtor em TypeScript dessa forma:

```
export class Telefone {
    constructor(a: boolean);
    constructor(a: boolean, b: number);
    constructor(a: boolean, b: number, c: string);
    constructor(public a?: boolean, public b?: number, c?: string){ }
}
```

Existe outra forma para realizar isso? Essa maneira acima não resolve sobrecargas como essa:

```
public Teste(bool a){}
public Teste(int b){}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TypeScript não resolveu esse problema que já havia no JS. Até tem como solucionar isso, mas deve ter alguma coisa que dificulte, talvez manter a interoperabilidade com código JS puro.

Tem que resolver do jeito que sempre fez:

```
class Classe {
    constructor(obj: any) {
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            //faz algo
        } else {
            //faz outra coisa
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [no **Playground** do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Classe%20%7B%0A%09constructor(obj%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(obj%20instanceof%20Array)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2Ffaz%20algo%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2Ffaz%20outra%20coisa%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A).

Ou ainda:

```
class Classe {
    constructor(obj: boolean | number) {
        if (typeof obj === "boolean") {
            //faz algo
        } else {
            //faz outra coisa
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [no **Playground** do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Classe%20%7B%0A%09constructor(obj%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20number)%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(typeof%20obj%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22boolean%22)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2Ffaz%20algo%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2Ffaz%20outra%20coisa%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Constructor.ts).

O normal do *overload* do TypeScript é apenas facilitar a chamada de um construtor com construções ligeiramente diferente, por isso que só o último pode ter uma implementação. Todos os outros obrigatoriamente precisam chamar o construtor único.

Answer (score 9):

Isso é impossível, porque quando o código for compilado para JavaScript vão existir duas funções com exatamente a mesma assinatura. Uma vez que JavaScript não suporta tipagem.

Você sempre precisa ter em mente que o código TypeScript vai compilar pra JavaScript. A única forma que o JavaScript tem de diferenciar sobrecargas é pela quantidade de parâmetros.

Minha dica pra você, é trocar o primeiro parâmetro para `any` (qualquer coisa) e validar dentro do corpo do construtor, não é uma forma ótima de se trabalhar, mas é o que a linguagem vai oferecer.

```js
constructor(arg: any) {
    if (obj instanceof bool) {

    } else if(obj instanceof number) {
        //faz outra coisa
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Olá, talvez deixar um construtor com tipo any não seja tão elegante, já que o tsc nos oferece a possibilidade utilizar **Generics**.

Pare essa situação que você citou funcionaria, embora ainda esta limitado a apenas um argumento.

> public Teste(bool a){}
>
> public Teste(int b){}

Ex:

```
export class Teste<T> {    
  constructor(obj: T){
  }
}
```