# Como fazer sobrecarga de métodos em TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, característica-linguagem

Estou com dificuldades em fazer a sobrecarga de métodos em TypeScript.

O método a ser sobrecarregado é um *object factory* `rect()` cujo uma das assinaturas possui quatro parâmetros numéricos e a outra assinatura possui apenas um parâmetro do tipo objeto de estrutura definida.

```
/**
 * Esse é um dos métodos que quero sobrecarregar,
 * com quatro parametros na assinatura.
 *
 * @param left 
 * @param top 
 * @param width 
 * @param height 
 */
static rect(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number): Rect2D {
    return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
}

/**
 * Esse é segundo método para sobrecarga,
 * conta com apenas um parâmetro estruturado na assinatura.
 *
 * @param param0 
 */
static rect({ left, top, width, height }: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number; }): Rect2D {
    return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
}
```

Como fazer essa sobrecarga, já que da maneira que estou fazendo resulta na seguinte mensagem de erro:

> `Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393)`

Acredito não ser relevante para a resposta mas se alguém pedir aqui está o fragmento do contexto contendo os métodos a serem sobrecarregados:

```
 class Point2D{
    
    private _x : number;
    public get x() : number {
        return this._x;
    }
    public set x(v : number) {
        this._x = v;
    }
    
    private _y : number;
    public get y() : number {
        return this._y;
    }
    public set y(v : number) {
        this._y = v;
    }    
    
    constructor(x: number, y: number){
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
    }
}

class Rect2D implements IRect2D{
    private _position: Point2D;
    public get position(): Point2D {
        return this._position;
    }
    public set position(value: Point2D) {
        this._position = value;
    }

    private _size: Size;
    public get size(): Size {
        return this._size;
    }
    public set size(value: Size) {
        this._size = value;
    }
    
    /**
     * Esse é um dos métodos que quero sobrecarregar,
     * com quatro parametros na assinatura.
     *
     * @param left 
     * @param top 
     * @param width 
     * @param height 
     */
    static rect(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number): Rect2D {
        return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
    }

   /**
    * Esse é segundo método para sobrecarga,
    * conta com apenas um parâmetro estruturado na assinatura.
    *
    * @param param0 
    */
    static rect({ left, top, width, height }: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number; }): Rect2D {
        return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
    }

    private constructor(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number ){
        this._position.x = left;
        this._position.y = top;
        this._size.width = width;
        this._size.height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso ajuda ou é duplicata? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365879/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158075/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Coleta de informações

No repositório do [projeto do *Microsoft* **TypeScript**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) a linguagem é definida como um superconjunto do JavaScript, adicionando tipos opcionais ao JavaScript e o seu código é compilado para JavaScript legível, baseado em padrões.

Na documentação [*Mozilla* sobre herança no **JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) está escrito que em JavaScript não existem "métodos" como os que conhecemos em linguagens baseadas em classes. Em JavaScript, qualquer função pode ser adicionada em um objeto em forma de propriedade. Uma herança de funções age como a herança de quaisquer outras propriedades que não sejam funções, e podemos inclusive realizar sobre-escrita de função. **Mas a documentação não cita a sobrecarga.**

Pesquisando na internet sobre sobrecarga de métodos em JavaScript eu achei essas frase no [StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25820610/11379709):

> Você não pode sobrecarregar o método em sentido estrito. Não é do
> jeito que ele é suportado em Java ou C#.
>
> O problema é que o JavaScript **NÃO** suporta nativamente a sobrecarga de
> métodos. Portanto, se visualizar / analisar duas ou mais funções com o
> mesmo nome, apenas considerará a última função definida e substituirá
> as anteriores.

Como o TypeScript é um superconjunto de JavaScript e os programas JavaScript existentes também são válidos, portanto as mesma regra que afasta sobrecarga de métodos em benefício da sobrescrição de método em JavaScript é válida em TypeScript.

Tudo isso que está escrito acima é verdade, mas então eu recebi nos comentários o link para a seguinte pergunta [Como usar sobrecarga de construtor em TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158075/como-usar-sobrecarga-de-construtor-em-typescript) e lá estão definidos dois conceitos fundamentais para que compreendesse qual era o meu erro de concepção para o problema de sobrecarga em TypeScript.

Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158078/137387) me veio a luz:

> Você precisa ter em mente que o código TypeScript vai compilar
> pra JavaScript. A única forma que o JavaScript tem de diferenciar
> sobrecargas é pela quantidade de parâmetros.

E estendendo essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158081/137387) para métodos em geral eu definitivamente saí do poço onde me encontrava:

> TypeScript não resolveu esse problema que já havia no JS.  O normal do
> overload do TypeScript é apenas facilitar a chamada de um construtor
> com construções ligeiramente diferente, por isso que só o último pode
> ter uma implementação. Todos os outros obrigatoriamente precisam
> chamar o construtor único.

## Resolução do problema

Diferente de *C#* ou *Java* o *TypeScript* não permite que haja uma implementação diferenciada para métodos sobrescritos, essa informação pode ser verifica e encontrada de forma espalhada na seção [Tipos Avançados na documentação TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Então eu não vou conseguir fazer isso aqui...

```
static rect(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number): Rect2D {
    return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
}

static rect({ left, top, width, height }: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number; }): Rect2D {
    return new Rect2D(left, top, width, height);
}
```

TypeScript não permite uma implementação diferenciada para cada método, pois mesmo se fosse permitido ao transpilar o código para Javascript a última implementação do método sebrescreveria a primeira implementação.

Então é como em *JavaScript* devo criar um único método o mais abrangente possível com relação aos parâmetros, método esse que será responsável pela implementação de todas a sobrecargas decidindo o que fazer e quando fazer baseado no tipo dos parâmetros passados levando em conta a rígida tipificação de parâmetros oferecida pela linguagem.

#### A solução é essa:

```
/**
 * São declaradas apenas as assinatura das sobrecargas para o método rect.
 * Essas são as assinaturas que vão estar disponíveis para o Intellisense.
 */
static rect({ left, top, width, height }: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number; }): Rect2D;
static rect(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number):Rect2D;    
static rect(point: Point2D, size: Size):Rect2D;

/**
 *  Essa é implementação comum a toda as sobrecargas
 *  Essa assinatura NÃO será disponibilizada pelo Intellisense, 
 *sendo assim o apresentará apenas três sobrecargas para o ambiente de desenvolvimento 
 *  A quantidade de parâmetro deve ser igual a quantidade de parâmetros da 
 *sobrecarga cujo a assinatura contenha mais parâmetros.
 *  O parâmetro arg1 é obrigatório enquanto os parâmetros arg2, arg3 e arg4 são 
 *marcados como opcionais pois a sobrecarga que exige a menor quantidade de parâmetros
 *exige ao menos um parâmetro. Caso houvesse uma sobrecarga de assinatura rect()
 *arg1 também deveria ser opcional.
 */
static rect(arg1: any, arg2?: any, arg3?: any, arg4?: any):Rect2D{
    //verifica o tipo do primeiro para determinar qual a sobrecarga utilizada
    switch(typeof arg1){
        case "number": 
            // Se o primeiro parâmetro for numérico a sobrecarga será rect(left: number, top: number, width: number, height: number)
            return new Rect2D(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        case "object": 
            // Se o primeiro parâmetro for objeto tenho duas possiveis implemetações
            if (arg1 instanceof Point2D){
                // Caso o objeto seja do tipo Point2D
                return new Rect2D(arg1.x, arg1.y, arg2.width, arg2.height);
            } else {
                      // Baseado na forte tipagem da linguagem presumisse que o argumento é o destructuring object 
                      //{ left, top, width, height }: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number; }
                      return new Rect2D(arg1.left, arg1.top, arg1.width, arg1.height);
                   }

    }
    //Código de guarda, caso o usuário da lib entre com uma composição 
    //parâmetros absurda retorna um objeto default.
    return new Rect2D(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

Código de teste do fragmento no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FatherlyProductiveDimension)