# É possível realizar uma sobrecarga (overload) com arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, funções, typescript, tipagem, sobrecarga

Tenho uma função onde o tipo do retorno depende do tipo do parâmetro. Consegui declarar essa sobrecarga com `function`, mas não com *arrow function*, pois recebo o erro:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'parseToDate2'.
'=>' expected.
```

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
// Funciona
function parseToDate<T extends string | null>(date: T): T extends string ? Date : null;
function parseToDate(date: string | null): Date | null {
  return typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : null;
}

// Não funciona
const parseToDate2 = <T extends string | null>(date: T): T extends string ? Date : null;
const parseToDate2 = (date: string | null): Date | null => 
  typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : null;
```

<sup>[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMEsD20CGAoAZjWAXJ1QAHFAJwGcBTAFUQBEUcKAeK0CgD0egBMzQycJeNADmoAD6hokADYyAfAApuDCgC5QVAJQbWHLr36DhYgPyh6jUBulyA3Jmx5kRUpRqWKy1RoFDRElKyMjoWqoG2MqAA3migoCQUOJAkBDgAnoQUiBigKlYAvEWgAOR+JiWg5tAUAO5hjN6MWtZB9mgAvmhoIKAAcgDHiKBYcPjosMgCruTUdKoATKAFoCxsnBQ8fOUBkpFK+eqaoXobW0b+Zg0UrZEOk9DTxLMei8ugTUc7YnvBoZ4RYLLeRxUAZLI5PLhIorMrGUSVap1a6fFo2YJ2IA)</sup>

Eu estou declarando a sobrecarga de forma errada ou ela não é suportada em *arrow functions*? Caso não seja suportada, por quê?

A princípio imaginei que, como funciona com `function`, deveria funcionar de algum jeito com *arrow function*.

Comment: Nesse caso não é por causa do `const`, que não deixa criar outra variável com o mesmo nome?

Comment: @hkotsubo é, parece ser isso mesmo ‍♂️. Fiz uns testes com `var`, `let` e `const` e vi a documentação do MDN, faz sentido. Existe uma "notação" diferente que permita a sobrecarga em *arrow functions*? Eu encontrei algumas respostas no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39187614/8839059) mas não consegui adaptar pro exemplo da minha pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir utilizar a sintaxe "parecida" com a de declarações de funções já que o TypeScript não entende que várias declarações de funções via *arrow functions* definidas com `const` (ou mesmo `let`) são definições de sobrecargas.

Para definições de sobrecargas utilizando aquela notação mais explícita, é só com declaração de funções mesmo. [Referir à documentação.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Você tem duas alternativas:

1. #### Não utilizar *arrow function*

   Nesse caso, você simplesmente irá a sintaxe de declaração de funções. Essa é a forma que eu prefiro, já que não tem muito motivo de usar *arrow function* aí. Estará, nesse caso, utilizando a notação que a linguagem escolheu para isso.

   Não vou dar exemplo porque já tem na pergunta.
2. #### Criar um novo tipo (com as sobrecargas definidas) e o atribuir à *arrow function*

   Você tem duas formas para fazer isso. Utilizar interfaces ou dois tipos de função unidos pelo operador de interseção de tipos, `&`.

   Exemplo que usa interfaces:

   ```
   interface GetParent {
     (selector: string): HTMLElement | null;
     (element: HTMLElement): HTMLElement | null;
   }

   const getParent: GetParent = (selector) => {
     if (typeof selector === 'string') {
       return document.querySelector(selector)?.parentElement ?? null;
     }

     return selector.parentElement;
   }
   ```

   <sup>[Ver no TSP.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOITABTlC5kDeAUMqcgBQDOEANhAmAPZQBcylYUoA5gJRsAJACoBZADIBROgFs8YZAB9kIAK40aAbhJlytCLPCDRkmXP7Jh4qfrmLlazUQC%20RIgkYgOybhmy5DaL44tgC8FNR0DMy8yCEAfITapMAwFGAAngAOEIypEfRMULEhYQDkHFwg3KUxxGT1yLhgKlAgyAAmjAgqBmAAdACOKtDpAMp6UVBUE4W8APx9mcHg1r3Ic3P26lr1LkmNGC1t%20ZOLy2CrclpOQA)</sup>

   Exemplo utilizando interseção de tipos de função:

   ```
   type GetParentViaSelector = (selector: string) => HTMLElement | null;
   type GetParentViaElement = (element: HTMLElement) => HTMLElement | null;
   type GetParent = GetParentViaSelector & GetParentViaElement;

   const getParent: GetParent = (selector) => {
     if (typeof selector === 'string') {
       return document.querySelector(selector)?.parentElement ?? null;
     }

     return selector.parentElement;
   }
   ```

   <sup>[Ver no TSP.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwAUCGAnCA7YA1AlkgyhADYQDGwA9ilALxQAUAzsWZSgFxSPAo7oDmASloA%20KAAkAKgFkAMgFESAWwzAoAHyjoArkSIBuAFChIseMjSZcSRRBWZaDFveCcpc2y%20E0x7hctUNLV0DY3BoOERUQLpIi1VrQhJyKigAMjMoy2w8T1UjQ1IKdG4ofnNozE44yrU6JhYUlG8xAG9DKE6oHAAzBhMICj7mZLZaGjoAcm5eAUnhdq6lqDRgbRR0KAATClJtFwA6AEdtCBQQJNYqBtGqQQB%20A7BavId7%20%20C9IyWAX0MOrqrdabEZXFBPF4BTBGH5AA)</sup>

<sup>Eu modifiquei os exemplos para simplificar a resposta. :) Mas genéricos também funcionam.</sup>

Devo ressaltar que, quando os tipos de retorno forem diferentes (tal como no exemplo da pergunta), a única saída é utilizar a própria sintaxe de sobrecarga explícita com as declarações de funções. [Aparentemente é um comportamento esperado.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33482)

Comment: Nesse exemplo de `getParent` me parece que funciona porque o retorno é sempre o mesmo, e no fim a assinatura seria algo como `getParent(selector: string | HTMLElement) => HTMLElement | null`. Se o retorno for diferente, como no caso da pergunta, não é possível fazer do modo 2?

Comment: [Exemplo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA8FMFsAcA2B7UATapbQM61QE7QAuyBAdsgFDECe8mACgIYE7QAqyAIs8ZgF5QAbyqhQACnitmsAFygcxAgEtyAcwCUC3v1AAfUOQCuiRGMnSCshSbPbQuzIbvmAvlSoBjZOSWgrdi4nBRY2Th4+QUk0KM1QAQA+EQsVADNJOgZkDNi9AQLQAHIlVQ0izVFxcSJiYwojaAB3RyiJPOhNAG4LDwta+vIjU0QevpAIGAQUdExaskocdHToInJ+HBp6JlYgyP4AJgSU8SkZeUVlNS0dKIsz6wvXB1cqPp8-YgDdiKcD0J+wSiRyE7TiCWSVVA6Uy2xy6CiCUKJSu5UqFhqJEGjRaTjB-G6vU8mLqDVcYyAA)

Comment: É, @RafaelTavares, não tinha testado esse caso, mas me parece que, com retornos de tipos incompatíveis, não dá para utilizar nenhum outro jeito senão a própria sintaxe de declaração de funções com as sobrecargas explícitas.

Comment: Pelas respostas na pergunta similar no SOen eu também não tinha conseguido. A solução 1 é ótima, pelo menos para minha situação. O que mais me importava saber é o porque eu não conseguia com *arrow functions* e se tinha outra alternativa. Sua resposta foi bem precisa nisso.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514588/112052), vale citar que no fim, o código TypeScript é transpilado para JavaScript, o que pode ajudar a explicar porque não é possível fazer o *overload* com *arrow functions*.

Se usarmos o seu código:

```js
function parseToDate<T extends string | null>(date: T): T extends string ? Date : null;
function parseToDate(date: string | null): Date | null {
  return typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : null;
}
```

Para testar eu usei o [Deno](https://deno.land/), pois com ele [é possível obter facilmente o arquivo JavaScript gerado a partir do TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61852068). No caso do código acima, o JavaScript gerado foi:

```js
"use strict";
function parseToDate(date) {
    return typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : null;
}
```

Ou seja, uma única função.

Mas eu também poderia fazer assim:

```js
// só recebe uma string ou null
function parseToDate < T extends string | null > (date: T): T extends string ? Date : null;
function parseToDate(date: string | null): Date | null;
// recebe 3 números
function parseToDate(date: number, month: number, year: number): Date | null;

// implementação: ver mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418160/112052
function parseToDate(date: any, month?: any, year?: any): Date | null {
    if (typeof date === 'string')
        return new Date(date);
    if (typeof date === 'number' && typeof month === 'number' && typeof year === 'number')
        return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
    return null;
}
```

Que o JavaScript resultante continuaria sendo uma única função:

```js
function parseToDate(date, month, year) {
    if (typeof date === 'string')
        return new Date(date);
    if (typeof date === 'number' && typeof month === 'number' && typeof year === 'number')
        return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
    return null;
}
```

Ou seja, todos os *overloads* se tornam uma única função, conforme já explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418160/112052).

---

#### E por que com *arrow function* não dá?

Com *arrow functions*, você na verdade está criando uma variável e atribuindo uma função como o seu valor. Ou seja, se você fizer algo como:

```js
let func = (x: number): number => x + 1;
func = (x: number): number => x - 1;

// func contém somente a última arrow function
console.log(func(11)); // 10
```

Na verdade você está **sobrescrevendo** o valor da variável `func` com **outro** valor (com **outra função**). A primeira função criada "se perde", e no fim você só tem a última. O JavaScript resultante é:

```js
let func = (x) => x + 1;
func = (x) => x - 1;
console.log(func(11));
```

Repare que tive que colocar o corpo da função e a "seta" (`=> x + 1` e `=> x - 1`), pois sem isso o código não compila. Ou seja, seu exemplo estava incompleto.

E no seu código, você usou `const`, então deu erro porque estava tentando criar a mesma variável duas vezes.

Mas tem um detalhe, eu não conseguiria fazer isso:

```js
let func = (x: number): number => x + 1;
// agora tem 2 parâmetros
func = (x: number, y:number): number => x + y;
```

Isso dá erro:

```
error: TS2322 [ERROR]: Type '(x: number, y: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(x: number) => number'.
func = (x: number, y:number): number => x + y;
```

Porque inicialmente a variável é do tipo "função que recebe um `number` e retorna um `number`", mas eu tentei colocar nela uma "função que recebe **dois** `number`'s e retorna um `number`", e como são tipos incompatíveis, dá o erro.

Ou seja, uma vez que uma variável tenha como valor uma *arrow function*, você não conseguiria setá-la com outra função com assinatura diferente (o que também impediria o *overload* - mas mesmo que isso fosse possível, na verdade não seria um *overload*, pois como eu já disse, você só estaria sobrescrevendo o valor da variável).

Nesse caso, um jeito de ter uma *arrow function* que aceita vários parâmetros de tipos diferentes (similar a uma `function` sobrecarregada) seria declarar os parâmetros da maneira mais genérica possível, dentro das opções que você quer considerar:

```js
let parseToDate2 = (date: string | number | null, month?: number, year?: number): Date | null => {
    if (typeof date === 'string')
        return new Date(date);
    if (typeof date === 'number' && typeof month === 'number' && typeof year === 'number')
        return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
    return null;
};
```

Que se transforma no seguinte JavaScript:

```js
let parseToDate2 = (date, month, year) => {
    if (typeof date === 'string')
        return new Date(date);
    if (typeof date === 'number' && typeof month === 'number' && typeof year === 'number')
        return new Date(year, month - 1, date);
    return null;
};
```

Ou seja, ele se torna basicamente a mesma função resultante do *overload* quando usamos `function` (considerando, é claro, [as diferenças entre `function` e *arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

Mas eu ainda preferiria usar a primeira opção (`function`), ou as sugestões da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514588/112052).